# Cassandra query PRIMARY KEY column cannot be restricted exception

Tags: cassandra

I have a table as bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE vroctest.sensor_data_3 (
    nodeid text,
    yyyymmdd int,
    hour int,
    minute int,
    second int,
    data_timestamp bigint,
    data_quality double,
    data_value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((nodeid, yyyymmdd), hour, minute, second, data_timestamp)
```

I need to do below query

```
SELECT nodeid, yyyymmdd, hour, minute, second, data_timestamp, data_quality, data_value
FROM vroctest.sensor_data_3  where nodeid in ('331ea1eb-d536-3f37-ba6b-ae02dbc736a4') and yyyymmdd in (20160701,20160702,20170701) and hour <=24 and hour >=0 and minute <61 and minute >=0 and second >=0 and second< 61 and data_timestamp >= 1467317265000 and data_timestamp <= 1498853265000;
```

however, it gives me exception

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Clustering column "minute" cannot be restricted (preceding column "hour" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)
```

Comment: you can't use range query on `data_timestamp` without specifying `hour, minute, second`

Comment: even if i restrict the hour,minute and second, it gives me exception, I editted my question.

Comment: You have to specify the value of hour, minute, second with equal relation

Comment: @AshrafulIslam that link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The following all pass. The first two are instructional. The last is a valid form of your complete query.

```
SELECT * FROM sensor_data_3  
    where nodeid in ('331ea1eb-d536-3f37-ba6b-ae02dbc736a4') 
    and yyyymmdd in (20160701,20160702,20170701) 
    and hour in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24) 
    and minute <61 and minute >=0;


SELECT * FROM sensor_data_3  
  where nodeid in ('331ea1eb-d536-3f37-ba6b-ae02dbc736a4') 
  and yyyymmdd in (20160701,20160702,20170701) 
  and (hour,minute) >= (0,0) 
  and (hour,minute) < (3,15);


SELECT nodeid, yyyymmdd, hour, minute, second, data_timestamp, data_quality, data_value FROM sensor_data_3  
    where nodeid in ('331ea1eb-d536-3f37-ba6b-ae02dbc736a4') 
    and yyyymmdd in (20160701,20160702,20170701) 
    and (hour,minute,second,data_timestamp) < (24,61,61,1467317265000) 
    and (hour,minute,second,data_timestamp) >= (0,0,0,1498853265000);
```

Hour, minute, second are discrete, allowing more than one solution. Cassandra, however, does not know this and does not want to hunt and peck for data to return. It wants one starting point and one ending point per partition. At least this is a mental model that often works for me.